# VB.Net 2010 - Need to reverse order of words (not letters) of string

Tags: vb.net, sorting, label

Happy Friday!

I have a loop that I output the string results to a label, but I want to reverse the order of words...

So instead of the label displaying:

Charlie
Beta
Alpha

I want it to display:

Alpha
Beta
Charlie

Code:

```
            For Each CollectionName In CollectionNames
                lblResult.Text &= vbCrLf + CStr(CollectionName.Name)
            Next
```

Comment: You can use `String.Split` to split into words wherever there is a space character. Then use `Array.Reverse` to reverse the order of the words, and finally `String.Join` to put the words back in a single string.

Comment: Can you walk me through how that would look with the provided code?

Comment: And the split would be Environment.NewLine

Comment: If the "words" are just the different `CollectionNames`, all you have to do is insert the words at the beginning of the label instead of appending to the end. `lblResult.Text = CStr(CollectionName.Name) & vbCrLf & lblResult.Text`

Comment: Yep, this worked as well!  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the string function Split and reverses the order before joining them.

```
    Function Reverse(ByVal input As String) As String
        Return String.Join(" ", input.Split(" ").Reverse())
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will split a string into words, reverse the words and then build a string with the reversed words.

```
Function ReverseWords(input As String) As String
    Dim words() As String = input.Split(" "c)
    Array.Reverse(words)
    Return String.Join(" ", words)
End Function
```

Note that this assumes that the words are originally separated by spaces. If they are separated by something else, you will need to adjust the arguments to the `Split` method.

Your comments suggest that you may simply want the reverse the values of `CollectionNames`. In that case, you can simply change your loop to this:

```
For Each CollectionName In CollectionNames
     lblResult.Text = CStr(CollectionName.Name) & vbCrLf & lblResult.Text
Next
```